# BizTalk 2010 : SharePoint REST with claims based authentication

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I'm trying to call one of the standard REST (ODATA) services to get data from a list in SharePoint. But I have issues with the claims based authentication.
I'm using BizTalk 2010 with the REST starter kit extension. The sendport I'm using is a WCF-Custom with webHttpBinding. The error I get is the following.

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: An HTTP Content-Type header is
>   required for SOAP messaging and none was found. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500)
>   Internal Server Error.

When I track some details with Fiddler, I can see the following error message.

> No credentials are available in the security package

Further in the Fiddler trace, I can see 2 HTTP 401 messages followed by the HTTP 500.
I've been trying a whole bunch of settings but nothing seems to work. This worked before the SharePoint server was migrated to 2013.

Did anybody try this before? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 0):

if you call the service outside of Biztalk(Postman or other tool), you modify , the content-type Header? if so, you have to add this header to your request:

```
Msg_Req(WCF.HttpHeaders)="content-type: "+<value>;
```

Comment: Just tried to add Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8 in a postman call to have the same headers as BizTalk. But it works in Postman. Not in BizTalk :(

Comment: try to display your headers content from biztalk. have a look on my blog entry https://boutalebhicham.wordpress.com/2018/01/01/wcf-webhttp-adapter-inound-rest-api-headers/

Comment: I have a fiddler trace with request/response headers but not sure how I can share it here. :-)

Comment: and the headers on Fiddler are the same for postman and biztalk request/response?

Comment: The only difference that I see is in "connection: Keep-Alive". BizTalk only uses that in the first GET. Postman uses this in all the calls. Even if I add it to the headers explicitly, it still only gets used in the first GET.

Comment: did you read Logs on the sharepoint server side? to have more informations? I think the problem  is occured when contacting the server with the request? another thing, try to run Postman with the same credentials of your biztalk host ones

Comment: We checked the logs on SharePoint and there we see an error that we are sending NTLM authentication but we need to send Negotiate, NTLM

Comment: in this case, please have a look on this article: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e96fd629-8326-4e52-bc17-344d407ed8f1/biztalk-wcfbasichttp-adapter-connecting-to-sharepoint-2013-web-services?forum=biztalkgeneral

Comment: I made a stupid workaround that does the trick for the moment. I call a c# method that does an HttpWebRequest to SharePoint at the beginning of my orchestration. That way I already have a session cookie and I avoid the error. It's not clean but it works. We are migrating to BizTalk 2016 soon, so I'll see if it works better in that version. Thanks for the help.